# Submit button is not disabling on ASP.NET MVC page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I have BackoutClaim page. On the Submit button click, I have to disable the button and from the POst method, when the response comes back, I have to enable button back.

In the below code, the button is not disabling. 
Appreciate your responses.

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

   <script type="text/javascript">
       function TrimThatNameThenSubmit() {
           var tableName = $('#tableName').val().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
           $('#tableName').val(tableName);
           **$('#Submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');**
           $('form:eq(0)').submit();

       }
</script>

<% 
    var messages = ViewData["messages"];
%>
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <div>
        <div class="Spacer"></div>

        <div class="RevertCaseStateHeader" align="center">
            <%= Html.TextBox("tableName", "Enter tableName to Backout Claim", new { @style = "width: 400px;" })%>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:TrimThatNameThenSubmit()"/>
        </div>
             <div class="RevertCaseStateSummary" align="center">
             <% if (messages != null)
                { %>
                    <%= Html.Encode(messages)%>
             <% } %>
             </div>
    </div>
<% } %>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the following line is useless : $('form:eq(0)').submit();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jQuery is selecting the button with id=Submit which doesn't exist, change your button definition to:

```
<input id="Submit" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:TrimThatNameThenSubmit()"/>
```